# Как переделать подключение?

Tags: php

Как переделать подключение под mssql ?

```
<?php
    class DBController {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $database = "phppot_examples";
        private $conn;

        function __construct() {
            $this->conn = $this->connectDB();
        }

        function connectDB() {
            $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
            return $conn;
        }

        function runQuery($query) {
            $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $resultset[] = $row;
            }       
            if(!empty($resultset))
                return $resultset;
        }

        function numRows($query) {
            $result  = mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            return $rowcount;   
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Есть обычное подключение к MSSQL

```
function getUNS()
{

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Data", "UID"=>"IDBAS", "PWD"=>"PASS");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( "localhost", $connectionInfo);

 return $conn;

}
```

Comment: А с чем сложность?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов хватит ли просто подставить sqlsrv_connect, sqlsrv_query, mssql_fetch_assoc, mssql_num_rows  функции ms

Comment: Да. Только подкорректировав список параметров, если нужно.

Comment: Офф топик конечно, но почему писать все это вручную когда есть фреймворки как laravel там 90% работы сделано за вас вам только осталось утилизировать их возможности, но если это хобби проект, то придратся конечно нельзя, я тоже люблю делать велосипеды.

Comment: Сделайте интерфейс, создайте два класса с подключениями наследующим интерфейс и используйте композицию, передав в конструктор подключение.